# ElasticSearch: Get duration between two fields script syntax error

Tags: elasticsearch

I've created this script in order to get a date difference between two fields:

```
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    def duration = doc[firstDateField].date - doc[secondDateField].date;
    duration.Hours;
}
```

In order to check it I'm requesting this `_search` request:

```
#docker exec -it es curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/living_team/fuas/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "script_fields": {
    "my_script": {
      "script": {
        "file": "dayDateDiff",
        "params": {
          "firstDateField": "timestamp",
          "secondDateField": "startTimestamp"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

ElasticSearch is telling me:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "script_exception",
      "reason" : "failed to run file script [dayDateDiff] using lang [groovy]"
    } ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query_fetch",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [ {
      "shard" : 3,
      "index" : "living_v1",
      "node" : "SSgkS5Y9QV-EmzaeP_7hKQ",
      "reason" : {
        "type" : "script_exception",
        "reason" : "failed to run file script [dayDateDiff] using lang [groovy]",
        "caused_by" : {
          "type" : "missing_property_exception",
          "reason" : "No such property: groovy for class: 94b4e4baddb8e121bd26f2098185e84d368e4162"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

So, the question would be, why do I need to set a field in order perform an script? and lastly, how can I send this script request correctly?

**EDIT**

I've changed my script:

```
new Period(doc[firstDateField].date, doc[secondDateField].date).getHours();
```

However, it's telling me now:

```
bbd8b73ce0b0dd070d07e63f11dcdad4fa12121d: 1: unable to resolve class Period
Nov 04 10:27:21 core-01 docker[3876]:  @ line 1, column 1.
Nov 04 10:27:21 core-01 docker[3876]:    new Period(doc[firstDateField].date, doc[secondDateField].date).getHours();
Nov 04 10:27:21 core-01 docker[3876]:    ^
```

It's telling me there's some problem with `Period`.

Comment: What are `unknown1` and `unknown2` in your query?

Comment: I've took a template from [this documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/modules-scripting.html). I don't really know what's that for.

Comment: I don't see any occurence of "unknown" in that doc

Comment: The `"unknown1"` and `"unknown2"` are `"script_fields"`and `"my_field"`. So, the question would be, why do I need to set a field in order perform an script? and lastly, how can I send this script request correctly?

Comment: then set `script_fields` and `my_field` accordingly and your query will work. `unknown1` and `unknown2` don't mean anything for ES

Comment: I've made your changes and it works now. Nevertheless, ES is telling me now there's some `missing_property_exeption`. I've edited the post.

Comment: The groovy package cannot be found in your script. Probably due to sandboxing. I don't think you need `use(groovy.time.TimeCategory)`

Comment: How do you suggest modifying the script file?

Comment: Something like `new Period(doc[firstDateField].date, doc[secondDateField].date).getHours()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127364/discussion-between-jordi-and-val).

Comment: try `new org.joda.time.Period(...)`

Comment: Sorry, It's telling me the same...

Comment: Are you certain that the error message is exactly the same ?

Comment: Before, it was telling me that `Period` can not be resolved, and now is telling me that `org.joda.time.Period` can not be resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another script that doesn't make use of the JODA `Period` class

Update your script file with this and that'll work:

```
(doc[secondDateField].date.millis - doc[firstDateField].date.millis) / 3600000
```

Comment: Ok, it works fine now. Nevertheless, let me ask you for how to enable JODA on ES groovy scripts. It's a bit more elegant using JODA. I'd like to take advantage of that, or whichever groovy library.

Comment: You may [customize the classloader whitelist](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-security.html#_customising_the_classloader_whitelist) in order to specify additional classes to be loaded in your scripts.