# ElasticSearch: Script not found in disk

Tags: elasticsearch

I've copied several scripts on `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/scripts`:

```
#ls /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/scripts
day.groovy  dayDateDiff.groovy  month.groovy  year.groovy
```

I'm trying to perform this request:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "Unable to find on disk file script [dayDateDiff.groovy] using lang [groovy]"
    } ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query_fetch",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [ {
      "shard" : 3,
      "index" : "living_v1",
      "node" : "2sER_Ua7SkCqh2a852JFfg",
      "reason" : {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Unable to find on disk file script [dayDateDiff.groovy] using lang [groovy]"
      }
    } ]
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

As you can see, it's telling me ES is unable to reach this `dayDateDiff` groovy script.

However, I'm able to perform `day.groovy` script:

```
#docker exec -it es curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/living_team/fuas/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "script_fields": {
    "my_script": {
      "script": {
        "file": "day",
        "params": {
          "field": "timestamp"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Response:

```
{
  "took" : 538,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "living_v1",
      "_type" : "fuas",
      "_id" : "58fb4509-9452-11e6-a361-02420a016207",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_routing" : "living_team",
      "fields" : {
        "my_script" : [ 17 ]
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "living_v1",
      "_type" : "fuas",
      "_id" : "2298eab3-9a8a-11e6-8f4a-02420a010a07",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_routing" : "living_team",
      "fields" : {
        "my_script" : [ 25 ]
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I've took a look on logs and:

> bbd8b73ce0b0dd070d07e63f11dcdad4fa12121d: 1: unable to resolve class
>   Period Nov 04 10:27:21 core-01 docker[3876]:  @ line 1, column 1. Nov
>   04 10:27:21 core-01 docker[3876]:    new
>   Period(doc[firstDateField].date,
>   doc[secondDateField].date).getHours(); Nov 04 10:27:21 core-01
>   docker[3876]:    ^

See on [other post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418191/elasticsearch-get-duration-between-two-fields-script-syntax-error)

Comment: What OS is this and how did you install ES?

Comment: I'm using official docker image v2.4.

Comment: However, I've just realized I'm able to perform `day.grrovy` script correctly...

Comment: There is no official ES docker image from Elastic for ES 2.x. If you're talking about the one from Docker hub, that's something the Docker guys built, not Elastic. The official one Elastic has is for ES 5: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-docker. Check the logs to see if the script from that particular file compiled successfully or not.

Comment: I've took a look on logs and the script doesn't compile (see post).

Comment: Yes, so fix your script or post it here :-).